# Perplexity formula in the t-SNE paper vs. in the implementation

Tags: matlab, entropy, tsne, perplexity

The perplexity formula in the official paper of t-SNE **IS NOT** the same as in its implementation.

In the [implementation](https://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/) (MATLAB):

```
% Function that computes the Gaussian kernel values given a vector of
% squared Euclidean distances, and the precision of the Gaussian kernel.
% The function also computes the perplexity of the distribution.
function [H, P] = Hbeta(D, beta)
    %Where D is a single row from the Euclidean distance matrix.
    P = exp(-D * beta);
    sumP = sum(P);
    H = log(sumP) + beta * sum(D .* P) / sumP; %<==== PERPLEXITY FORMULA
    P = P / sumP;
end
```

However, in the [paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume9/vandermaaten08a/vandermaaten08a.pdf), perplexity is defined as in [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZBNb.png):

$$ \mathrm{Perp}(P_i) = 2^{H(P_i)} $$
$$ H(P_i) = -\sum _j p_{j|i} \log_2{p_{j|i}} $$

I understand they must be equivalent. The question is: how can this equivalence be shown?

Comment: Note that in the code, `sumP` is not necessarily unity, which means that until the very end, `P` does not contain probabilities.  (It is strange that `P` is not immediately normalized, because that would simplify the formula for `H` and immediately answer your question, I believe.)

Comment: @whuber I suspect the reason to compute it in this roundabout way was to prevent possible numerical problems -- see my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given $i$, the similarities $p_{j|i}$ are obtained from Euclidean distances $d_{ij}$ via a Gaussian similarity kernel and then normalized to sum to one: $$p_{j|i} = \frac{\exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})}.$$ Plugging this into the entropy formula, we obtain:
\begin{align}
H(p_{\cdot|i}) &= -\sum_j p_{j|i} \log p_{j|i}=
-\sum_j \frac{\exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})} \log \frac{\exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})}\\
&=-\frac{1}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})}\sum_j \exp(-\beta d_{ij}) \big[\log \exp(-\beta d_{ij}) - \log\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})\big]=\\
&=\frac{1}{\sum_k \exp(\beta d_{ik})}\sum_j \exp(-\beta d_{ij}) \big[-\beta d_{ij} - \log\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})\big]=\\
&=\frac{\beta\sum_j d_{ij} \exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})} + \frac{\sum_j \exp(-\beta d_{ij}) \log\sum_j \exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})}\\
&=\frac{\beta\sum_j d_{ij} \exp(-\beta d_{ij})}{\sum_k \exp(-\beta d_{ik})} +  \log\sum_j \exp(-\beta d_{ij}).\\
\end{align}

This is what is computed by

```
P = exp(-D * beta);
sumP = sum(P);
H = log(sumP) + beta * sum(D .* P) / sumP;
```

There are two questions left. First, shouldn't we have used $\log_2$ and not $\log$? Turns out this does not matter, because $$2^{-\sum a_i\log_2 a_i} = \prod a_i^{-a_i} = e^{-\sum a_i \log a_i},$$ so one can use any power/logarithm to define perplexity. The paper uses binary logarithm while the Matlab code uses natural logarithm.

Second, why wasn't this function written simply as

```
P = exp(-D * beta);
sumP = sum(P);
P = P / sumP;
H = -sum(P .* log(P));
```

I think it was a way to avoid possible numerical problems due to very small values of $p_{j|i}$. As written, there is no need to explicitly compute `log(P)` which would have large absolute value) and then to multiply `P` (very close to zero) with `log(P)` (very far from zero).